# Get Hidden Field Value

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a `GridView` defined as follows:

```
<asp:GridView ID="myGridView" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server"
OnLoad="myGridView_Load" OnRowCommand="myGridView_Command" OnRowEditing="myGridView_RowEditing" OnRowDeleting="myGridView_RowDeleting" DataKeyNames="ID" > 
  <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" Visible="false" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="BirthDate" Visible="false" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First Name" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="Last Name" />
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Other">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="editLB" runat="server" Text="edit" CommandName="Edit" />
        <asp:LinkButton ID="deleteLB" runat="server" Text="delete" CommandName="Delete" />
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>   
</asp:GridView>
```

When a user clicks the edit button, I need to get the value of the `BirthDate` column. To attempt this, I have tried the following:

```
protected void myGridView_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
  GridViewRow row = gvUsers.Rows[e.NewEditIndex];
  DateTime birthDate = (DateTime)(row.Cells[1].Text);

  // Does not work
}
```

I know it has something to do with the fact that the column is not visible. The column must be hidden. But I need to get that value— how can I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that when the Visibility property of the `BoundField` is set to false the column isn't rendered to the client. A work around would be to use a `HiddenField` within a `TemplateField` instead.

```asp
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" 
                         Value='<%# Eval("BirthDate") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" 
                         Value='<%# Eval("BirthDate") %>' />
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

```cs
protected void GridView_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = GridView.Rows[e.NewEditIndex];     
    HiddenField  hidden = (HiddenField)row.Cells[0].FindControl("HiddenField1");
    DateTime birthDate = Convert.ToDateTime(hidden.Value);
}
```

**EDIT**

The above method still renders the column in the table, so you end up with an empty column. It works but not the best solution, here's a way the hide the BirthDate field but still get its value in the `RowEditing` event handler. Just keep in mind that the BirthDate is still rendered to the client, just not displayed.

```html
<style type="text/css">
    .hide
    {
        display:none;
    }
</style>

<asp:BoundField DataField="BirthDate">
    <ItemStyle CssClass="hide"/>
</asp:BoundField>
```

```cs
protected void GridView_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex];
    DateTime birthDate = Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells[1].Text);
}
```

Comment: I tried second one but it hided just values and header still exist. how can I hide also header? (I cannot use visible= false because I neet its data)

Comment: set the header css class to hide

Answer (score 5):

To hide the content as well as the Header in the Grid use the below code:
and access the column as usual. `GridView.SelectedRow.Cells[index].Text;`

```
<style type="text/css">
.hide
{
    display:none;
}
```

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="MailRoomID" HeaderText="Mailroom ID" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ShowHeader="false" ><ItemStyle CssClass="hide" /><HeaderStyle CssClass="hide"/></asp:BoundField>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have done something like this (adapting to your example):

```
string[] keyList = new string[1];   
keyList[0] = "BirthDate";  
myGridView.DataKeyNames = keyList;
```

I then bound the GridView with a DataTable that has a column named "BirthDate". The data under this column would be stored under the DataKeyName specified above.

To get the desired value, I would do something like this:

```
protected void myGridView_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)  
{   
  DataKeyArray keyList = myGridView.DataKeys as DataKeyArray;
  if (keyList != null)       
    DateTime birthDate = keyList[e.NewEditIndex];    
}
```

I realize that this doesn't involve hidden fields, however.

Comment: DataKeyNames property is used to uniquely identify each row, it should be used for Primary Keys.

Comment: Excellent point. When I used DataKeyNames that's exactly what I used them for.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the following article that shows how to access GridView invisible columns:

http://www.highoncoding.com/Articles/178_Access_GridView_Invisible_Columns.aspx

The idea is to basically use a TemplateField column instead of a BoundColumn.

Answer (score 0):

this is one way to get data from underlying data

```
protected void myGridView_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
  GridViewRow row = gvUsers.Rows[e.NewEditIndex];
DateTime birthDate = Convert.ToDateTime(DataBinder.Eval(row.DataItem, "BirthDate"));
}
```

Comment: I don't think the DataItem is populated outside of a data binding context. Inside of the RowEditing event handler DataItem will be null.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the hiddenfield suggestion that Phaedrus suggested, and then in your code behind; use something like this:

```
GridViewRow row = gvUsers.Rows[e.NewEditIndex];
var hfBirthDate = (HiddenField)row.FindControl("hfBirthDate");
DateTime birthDate = DateTime.Parse(hfBirthDate.Value);
```